# How to tell which item was checked/unchecked in a listbox

Tags: vb.net

How could I tell which item's state (checked/unchecked) was changed in a checkedlistbox?
I know how to trigger an event when an item's state was changed, but I don't know how to tell WHICH item. Any suggestions?

P.S. I'm using Visual Basic with .net 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The you want is reffered to by `ItemCheckEventArgs.Index`
Checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.itemcheckeventargs.index.aspx

At the bottom:-

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemCheck1(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) _
    Handles ListView1.ItemCheck

    If (e.CurrentValue = CheckState.Unchecked) Then
        price += Double.Parse( _
        Me.ListView1.Items(e.Index).SubItems(1).Text)
    ElseIf (e.CurrentValue = CheckState.Checked) Then
        price -= Double.Parse( _
            Me.ListView1.Items(e.Index).SubItems(1).Text)
    End If 

    ' Output the price to TextBox1.
    TextBox1.Text = CType(price, String)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CheckedItems` collection of the checked list box will give you each item in the list that is checked, typically this is wired up to a button event, like this:

```
Private Sub WhatIsChecked_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles WhatIsChecked.Click
    For Each itemChecked In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        ' Do something with each checked item
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: In this example, there is a button named `WhatIsChecked`.

If you just want to know when an individual checkbox changes in the list, then use this:

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender as Object, e as ItemCheckEventArgs) _ 
 Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    Dim messageBoxVB as New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Index", e.Index)
    messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
    messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "NewValue", e.NewValue)
    messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
    messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "CurrentValue", e.CurrentValue)
    messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
    MessageBox.Show(messageBoxVB.ToString(),"ItemCheck Event")
End Sub
```